# Nicedit & Sortable conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nicedit

When I use the jquery sortable plugin on a div that contains a nicedit instance, I cannot type in the text area if I focus on it with a left click.  I either have to tab to it, or after I left click on it, right click on it.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of trial and error and searching, I found that I had to bind a click to the div the editor replaces the textarea with and force it to focus:

```
$('.nicEdit-main').click(
         function()
              {
                $(this).focus()
              }
         );
```

After everything was done loading up.